# Not able to get defined variable value in function

Tags: java

I have below code.

```
public class TestClass {

  @Value("${api.key}")
  private String apiKey;

  @Value("${api.version}")
  private String apiVersion;

  private String baseURL = apiKey + "/" + apiVersion;

  public test() {
     LOGGER.debug("Val {}", baseURL);
  }
}
```

When I try to run it always give null as a result.

I have same baseURL and in Once class I have multiple functions, so if any changes come no need to change in every function.

Comment: What exact output do you get?

Comment: Why you want to inject a value into a field just to have another field which points to the other field with the injected value. You also can just use `LOGGER.debug("Val {}", configKey);`

Comment: I would like to use same `baseURL` in different functions. So to make it global above class. I don't have to change in each and every function.

Comment: you could also do this using configKey. I am a little bit confused, why do you want static field to point to non static mutable field

Comment: I could be wrong but I think static fields are initialized first, before instance fields - at the moment when `baseURL` is initialized `configKey` is still null.

Comment: Hi @Steyrix  I have updated the question

Comment: The current code doesn't even compile. You can't reference an instance field while initializing a static field.

Comment: I am not forcing to use `final` keyword. It's optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static values are initialised before the beans creation, which means the values to the member fields will be injected after the static variable is assigned with values and thats the reason it's coming null.

What can be done is, you can use Spring's @PostConstruct above an init function and perform your operation there and assign the base url to the member variable, which can be accessed later.
Post Construct makes sure your code inside function is executed(only once) after your bean gets created.

```
    
public class TestClass {

  @Value("${api.key}")
  private String apiKey;

  @Value("${api.version}")
  private String apiVersion;

  private final String baseURL;

  @PostConstruct
  private init() {
    baseURL = apiKey + "/" + apiVersion;
  }

  public String getBaseUrl() {
    return baseUrl;
  }

  public test() {
     LOGGER.debug("Val {}", baseURL);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the use of `getBaseUrl` function?

Comment: That just a getter function for variable baseURL, you can ignore if you dnt need it. 

Simply i have added, lets say if you inject TestClass bean using @Autowired to some another bean and, you need to access baseURL over there as well, in that case getter function can be useful

Answer (score 0):

This is because static members will be initialized before the value of configKey will be injected. You can access configKey only if your TestClass is fully initialized. You can try something like this:

```
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Log4j
@Component
public class TestClass {

    @Value("${config.key}")
    private String configKey;

    @PostConstruct
    void initialized() {
        this.test();
    }

    public void test() {
        log.debug(String.format("configKey: '%s'", this.configKey));
    }
}
```

And you should insert the following line into your application.properties:

```
config.key=something
```